# Setting up custom format and filter for Boost.Log: nothing happens

Tags: c++, boost, boost-log

I have issues configuring Boost.Log. I want a single, global logger to print to `std::cout` all messages with severity `debug` or higher. The format of the message is a simple `"foobar: "` prefix.

What I expect to be printed: `foobar: foobar`.

What is printed: nothing.

Sample code:

`main.c`:

```cpp
#include "logger.hh"

int main() {
    init_logger();
    using namespace boost::log::trivial;
    BOOST_LOG_SEV(my_logger::get(), debug) << "foobar";
}
```

`logger.hh`:

```cpp
#include <boost/log/sources/global_logger_storage.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sources/severity_feature.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sources/severity_logger.hpp>
#include <boost/log/trivial.hpp>

BOOST_LOG_GLOBAL_LOGGER(my_logger, boost::log::sources::severity_logger_mt<>)
void init_logger();
```

`logger.cc`:

```cpp
#include "logger.hh"

#include <boost/core/null_deleter.hpp>
#include <boost/log/core.hpp>
#include <boost/log/expressions.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sinks/sync_frontend.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sinks/text_ostream_backend.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sources/logger.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sources/record_ostream.hpp>
#include <boost/log/trivial.hpp>
#include <boost/log/utility/setup/common_attributes.hpp>
#include <boost/smart_ptr/make_shared_object.hpp>
#include <boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp>

#include <iostream>

namespace logging = boost::log;
namespace sinks = boost::log::sinks;
namespace expr = boost::log::expressions;
namespace src = boost::log::sources;

BOOST_LOG_GLOBAL_LOGGER_INIT(my_logger, src::severity_logger_mt) {
    src::severity_logger_mt<> lg;
    return lg;
}

void init_logger() {
    // Construct the sink
    auto sink = boost::make_shared<sinks::synchronous_sink<sinks::text_ostream_backend>>();
    boost::shared_ptr<std::ostream> stream(&std::cout, boost::null_deleter{});
    sink->locked_backend()->add_stream(stream);
    sink->set_formatter(expr::stream << "foobar: " << expr::smessage);       // ???
    sink->set_filter(logging::trivial::severity >= logging::trivial::debug); // ???
    // Register the sink in the logging core
    logging::core::get()->add_sink(sink);
}
```

I do not understand what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

While browsing other answers and experimenting, I have realized a few things that are not stated clearly in the Boost.Log documentation and tutorial.

`severity_logger_mt` must be instantiated with a concrete type that represents a severity struct, with default being just an `int` (perhaps to eat any user-provided enums). An example of a severity struct is a `severity_level` struct from `boost::log::trivial::severity_level`.

The code below is a full working example:

`main.cc`:
no changes.

`logger.hh`:

```cpp
#pragma once

#include <boost/log/sources/global_logger_storage.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sources/severity_feature.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sources/severity_logger.hpp>
#include <boost/log/trivial.hpp>

BOOST_LOG_GLOBAL_LOGGER(
    my_logger, boost::log::sources::severity_logger_mt<boost::log::trivial::severity_level>)

void init_logger();
```

`logger.cc`:

```cpp
#include "logger.hh"

#include <boost/core/null_deleter.hpp>
#include <boost/log/core.hpp>
#include <boost/log/expressions.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sinks/sync_frontend.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sinks/text_ostream_backend.hpp>
#include <boost/log/trivial.hpp>
#include <boost/smart_ptr/make_shared_object.hpp>
#include <boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp>

#include <iostream>

namespace logging = boost::log;
namespace expr = boost::log::expressions;
namespace sinks = boost::log::sinks;
namespace src = boost::log::sources;

BOOST_LOG_GLOBAL_LOGGER_INIT(my_logger, src::severity_logger_mt<logging::trivial::severity_level>) {
    src::severity_logger_mt<logging::trivial::severity_level> lg;
    return lg;
}

void init_logger() {
    // Construct the sink
    auto sink = boost::make_shared<sinks::synchronous_sink<sinks::text_ostream_backend>>();
    boost::shared_ptr<std::ostream> stream(&std::cout, boost::null_deleter{});
    sink->locked_backend()->add_stream(stream);
    sink->set_formatter(expr::stream << "foobar: " << expr::smessage);
    sink->set_filter(logging::trivial::severity >= logging::trivial::debug);
    // Register the sink in the logging core
    logging::core::get()->add_sink(sink);
}
```

An alternative way to adding a new sink explicitly is to use a helper function, such as `add_console_log()`.

```cpp
#include <boost/log/utility/setup/console.hpp>
namespace keywords = boost::log::keywords;
BOOST_LOG_GLOBAL_LOGGER_INIT(my_logger, src::severity_logger_mt<logging::trivial::severity_level>) {
    src::severity_logger_mt<logging::trivial::severity_level> lg;
    logging::add_console_log(std::cout,
                             keywords::format = (expr::stream << "foobar: " << expr::smessage));
    logging::core::get()->set_filter(logging::trivial::severity >= logging::trivial::debug);
    return lg;
}
```

Comment: `add_console_log` adds a new sink, it does *not* modify any previously registered sink. By registering a new sink you disable the default sink that is used when there are no user-added sinks.

Comment: Also, `BOOST_LOG_GLOBAL_LOGGER_INIT` initializer may be executed multiple times, even though only one global logger instance is guaranteed. This means multiple sinks may be added in your example.

Comment: Hi @AndreySemashev. I don't think I understand your last message. Do you mean it in a sense that there can be ghost sinks that are invisible to the user, or that the user can create multiple sinks if they want so (e.g. add_console_log, add_file_log, add_sink)? If it's the latter, do I understand correctly, that for one severity type the user can create only distinct kinds of sinks, i.e. cannot call add_console_log twice? I make this conclusion based on the fact that I have to set_filter the same severity type that is used in template of BOOST_LOG_GLOBAL_LOGGER_INIT.

Comment: I was also under impression that helper functions change the default sink due to the fact that I had to call set_filter on the logging::core::get(). Could you please point the part of the documentation that explains the logic and architecture of the logging system in detail? Also, edit suggestions are welcome.

Comment: I cannot say I read every single word from start to finish, but reading through most parts I did not obtain understanding of all these very important parts: what happens with user-added sinks, with default sinks, with streams, with severity. This just happened to work.

Comment: @AveMilia 1. Every call to `add_*_sink` or `core::add_sink` registers a new sink in the logging core. None of it modifies any previously registered sinks. For example, if you call `add_console_log` twice, there will be two console sinks, meaning that any log record, provided that it is not discarded by filters, will be printed on the console twice - once per sink. 2. When no sinks are registered by user, a default (implicit) sink is used. That sink is not configurable and outputs log records to console in a fixed format.

Comment: 3. Sinks are not associated with severity levels or any other attributes per se. What makes a sink recognize and use an attribute are filters and formatters. You can set a filter and/or formatter that will recognize multiple different types of severity levels. 4. You can modify a previously registered sink through a pointer to it. The pointer is returned from `add_*_sink` methods (and you pass the pointer to `core::add_sink`). In this sense, there are no "ghost" sinks - every sink is accessible and accountable as long as you keep a pointer to it.

Comment: 5. My comment re. `BOOST_LOG_GLOBAL_LOGGER_INIT` means that the library makes not guarantees that the logger initializer is only run once (or that it is not run concurrently). The library only guarantees that it keeps a single instance of the constructed logger. With regard to your code, this means that `add_console_log` may be called multiple times, which would register multiple equivalent console sinks, which would result in duplicate output on the console. 6. The library design is documented [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/design.html).

Comment: 7. For the majority of sink types, one sink backend corresponds to one output (e.g. an output stream, like console or file). One exception to this is `text_ostream_backend`, which supports outputting the same formatted string to multiple output streams. However, this feature is not used by `add_*_sink` methods - as documented, those methods add a new sink every time they are called. So, to keep things simple you may think that one sink corresponds to one output stream.